# Clustering ~100,000 Short Strings in Python

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, levenshtein-distance

I want to cluster ~100,000 short strings by something like q-gram distance or simple "bag distance" or maybe Levenshtein distance in Python.  I was planning to fill out a distance matrix (100,000 choose 2 comparisons) and then do hierarchical clustering with [pyCluster](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/software.htm#pycluster).   But I'm running into some memory problems before even getting off the ground.  For example, the distance matrix is too large for numpy.

```
aa = numpy.zeros((100000, 100000))
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Does this seem like a reasonable thing to do?  Or am I doomed to memory problems in this task?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: 10 billion is a large number.

Comment: I am thinking of an approach to this fun problem, but I miss some information. Please detail a bit more what exactly you are trying to accomplish, as well as why and the possible assumptions/limitations. Here are 2 particular questions. 1) Can you have replicate strings in your analysis? 2) Do you really need all 2-by-2 distances or say only a proportion of the smaller distances for a given string would be enough? Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

100,000 * 100,000 * 32bits = 40 GBytes, which would be *a lot* of RAM, so yes, you need to find another way.  (And even if you could fit this data into memory, the calculation would take too long.)

One common and easy shortcut is to cluster a small random subset of the data, and after you find the clusters of this subset, just put the rest of the points into the clusters where they fit best.

Comment: Doesn't your machine have 4096GB of memory?

Comment: Thanks for the calculations.  Yes, the current approach seems impossible.

Comment: Sorry, just nitpicking here, two years later: Since the distance matrix is symmetrical, it would be 20 GB.

Answer (score 2):

10 billion elements is an awful lot. I don't know from q-grams, but if that matrix is sparse, you could use a 200,000-ish element dict.

Comment: I have read about sparse matrices.  Unclear if the data is sparse, as you say...I would have to do more testing.  Also unclear (to me) if pyCluster can handle sparse matrices.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? That's quite an important question I think.

Comment: In principle, such a matrix would not be sparse. One problem of creating such a sparse matrix is how you determine if some matrix element is to be evaluated or not.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the matrix? I assume you want to use a matrix for speed?

I have a k-means cluster algorithm (rather than a hierarchical cluster algorithm) and this calculates node distances as required. Probably only viable for fast distance metrics, though. And you have more data than I do - but you are bound by memory limitations.

Comment: Yes, something like this seems to be the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a method in Machine Learning called Embedding which can, in principle, search for a solution for this problem using *O*(n+m) memory instead of *O*(n*m) (n=10^5 items, m=10^5 features). Unfortunately, I don't know of an available source code that is implemented in O(m+n). See:

   > Euclidean Embedding of Co-occurrence Data. 
   >   Amir Globerson, Gal Chechik, Fernando Pereira and Naftali Tishby. 
   >   Journal of Machine Learning Research, JMLR, 8 (Oct), 2007. [pdf](http://ai.stanford.edu/~gal/Papers/Chechik_JMLR2007_MISM.pdf) / 
   >   [Matlab code](http://ai.stanford.edu/~gal/code.html)
2. There could be other solutions. I think that you should ask this question at a forum of Machine Learning people, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/, or even more specific for language processing: http://metaoptimize.com/qa/.